# is it safe to backup ext4 partition with partimage , which is detected as a ext3 partition

Tags: ext4, ext3, backup, partimage

I use `partimage` to backup my `ext4` partition, but during backup, the partition was detected as an `ext3` partition. So I'm wondering if this can cause something bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page

`Limitations - Partimage does not support ext4 or btrfs filesystems.`

It is unwise to use it for ext4 as long as that message is on their website.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use extents, ext4 can be mounted as ext3.

Comment: If I don't know the details of filesystem technology, does it mean that there is no problem and nothing will be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Use [fsarchiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSArchiver) instead. fsarchiver supports ext4.

It can be thought of as a successor to Partimage, which has mostly ceased development since 2009. It is written by one of the Partimage developers, Francois Dupoux, and has other features which Partimage lacks. See the comparison table [FSARCHIVER VS PARTIMAGE](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Fsarchiver_vs_partimage).

Answer (score 0):

You need `partclone.ext4`. It copy partitions without zero sectors. Works like a charm https://partclone.org/

Backup partition example:
`partclone.ext4 -c -s /dev/sda1 -o dir_with_backups/sda1.img`

`-c` means copy mode

`-s` means source (what to backup)

`-o` means output (where to save backup)

Restore partition example:
`partclone.ext4 -r -o /dev/sda1 -s dir_with_backups/sda1.img`

`-r` means recover mode

Comment: This is true, now in 2020. It presumably wasn't true in 2012 when the question was asked, because of [a reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37638/100397) to `partimage` not yet supporting `ext4` or `btrfs` filesystems

Comment: (And no, I didn't downvote you.)

Comment: This user is spraying multiple sites in the Stack Exchange network with this link. Flagging as spam.

Comment: I believe the answer attracted spam flags due to its phrasing and nearly-bare link. A little explanation of how to use the tool would go a long way towards making this a more useful answer.